# why such the shader snippet related to one variable bound to "TEXCOORD0“ semantics was divided by 5

Tags: shader, gpu, ogre

i'm new to shader programming. just some confuse about the following code,which "noiseCoord.xy" was divided by 5, and that's really large denominator.for all i know, noiseCoord should range from 0.0 to 1.0 as usually.  actually i've so much situation like this, was divide by a large denominator. is it experimental value? hope your guys help me figure it out. thank you in advanced!

```
       //Vertex program
        void main_vp_old(
                float4 pos          : POSITION,
                float4 normal       : NORMAL,
                float2 tex          : TEXCOORD0,

                out float4 oPos     : POSITION,
                out float fresnel   : COLOR,
                out float3 noiseCoord : TEXCOORD0,
                out float4 projectionCoord : TEXCOORD1,

                uniform float4x4 worldViewProjMatrix,
                uniform float3 eyePosition, // object space
                uniform float fresnelBias,
                uniform float fresnelScale,
                uniform float fresnelPower,
                uniform float timeVal,
                uniform float scale,  // the amount to scale the noise texture by
                uniform float scroll, // the amount by which to scroll the noise
                uniform float noise  // the noise perturb as a factor of the  time
                )
        {
            oPos = mul(worldViewProjMatrix, pos);
            ..........................................
            ..........................................
            // Noise map coords
            noiseCoord.xy = (tex + (timeVal * scroll)) * scale;
            noiseCoord.z = noise * timeVal;
            ..........................................
        }







 // Fragment program for distorting a texture using a 3D noise texture
    void main_fp(
            float3 noiseCoord           : TEXCOORD0,
            float4 projectionCoord      : TEXCOORD1,
            float3 eyeDir               : TEXCOORD2,
            float3 normal               : TEXCOORD3,

            out float4 col      : COLOR,

            uniform float4 tintColour,
            uniform float noiseScale, 
            uniform float fresnelBias,
            uniform float fresnelScale,
            uniform float fresnelPower,
            uniform sampler2D noiseMap : register(s0),
            uniform sampler2D reflectMap : register(s1),
            uniform sampler2D refractMap : register(s2)
            )
    {
        // Do the tex projection manually so we can distort _after_
        float2 final = projectionCoord.xy / projectionCoord.w;

        // just here, why was divided by such 5 instead of others?
        float3 noiseNormal = (tex2D(noiseMap, (noiseCoord.xy / 5)).rgb - 0.5).rbg * noiseScale;  


        final += noiseNormal.xz;

        // Fresnel
        //normal = normalize(normal + noiseNormal.xz);
        float fresnel = fresnelBias + fresnelScale * pow(1 + dot(eyeDir, normal), fresnelPower);

        // Reflection / refraction
        float4 reflectionColour = tex2D(reflectMap, final);
        float4 refractionColour = tex2D(refractMap, final) + tintColour;

        // Final colour
        col = lerp(refractionColour, reflectionColour, fresnel);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like it has no good reason to be there to me. The shader code is already applying a scale factor in the vertex shader (the uniform called 'scale'). Applying another hardcoded scale factor in the fragment shader seems unjustified to me. It would be many times more efficient to just multiply the uniform 'scale' by 0.2f on the CPU.